# Decent way to parse a string for a complex format

Tags: php, regex, parsing, string-parsing

I am trying to parse Science Bowl questions from a large string.
The general format is as follows:

```
PART
SUBJECT QuestionType Question goes here.
ANSWER: Answer goes here.
```

For example, the string might look like this:

```
A Team Questions 5/7/2014

TOSS-UP
1) PHYSICS Multiple Choice Gravity is 10 m/s^2. How far in meters will an object fired at 10 meters per second travel if it is fired at an angle of 22.5 degrees from the horizontal?
W) 5sqrt(2)
X) 10
Y) 10sqrt(2)
Z) 20
ANSWER: W) 5sqrt(2)

BONUS
1) PHYS Short Answer A proton is which of the following:
1) Fermion
2) Hadron
3) Lepton
4) Boson
5) Baryon
ANSWER: 1, 2, 5



TOSS-UP
2) EARTHSCI Short Answer What is the greatest prime factor of 5^2014+5^2015+5^2016+5^2017?
ANSWER: 13

...more tossup/bonus pairs...
```

The following regex (simplified version; the real one needs to be generated by a large PHP function) is less than 50% accurate. The goal is to capture each of the components (part, subject, type, question, answer) individually.

```
/(TOSS-UP|BONUS)\n\s*(?:([0-9]+)[\.\)])?\s*(BIO(?:LOGY)?|CHEM(?:ISTRY)?|PHYS(?:ICS|ICAL(?: SCIENCE)?)?|MATH(?:EMATICS)?|E(?:SS)?(?:ARTH)? ? ?(?:AND)? ?(?:SPACE)? ?(?:SCI(?:ENCE)?)?)\s*(Multiple Choice|Short Answer)\s*([^\n]+)(:?\s*W[\s\S]([^\n]+)\s*X[\s\S]([^\n]+)\s*Y[\s\S]([^\n]+)\s*Z[\s\S]([^\n]+))?\s*\nANSWER[\s\S]([^\n]+)/i
```

My question is, is there a better way to do this than bashing with a massive regex with tons of capture groups? If not, is there a better way to conveniently write a regex?
Or is the entire paradigm messed up and there's a way to avoid string parsing entirely?

I use plain old PHP (preg_replace) although I can be convinced to switch to something else.
A test file can be found here, if you want: http://www.filedropper.com/compiled11-26-13

Thank you!

Comment: Use this http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained